# Relation between giving the form of an operator in a given representation, and bra ket notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, representation-theory, quantum-states

So I understand that kets are abstract objects that are the elemnets of a Hilberts space. Say  $|\psi \rangle$.

We can write this ket in a position representation $\langle r|\psi \rangle = \psi(r)$, effectively 'choosing a basis'- the position basis- for our Hilbert space. I suppose one always has to ensure that the cardinality of the chosen basis and Hilbert space has to be the same, which isn't much of a problem in physics problems. In any case, we have chosen a basis foor our Hilbert space.

Now my question is, what does it mean to write an operator in a particular basis representaion, and how does it translate to ket notation.

If we have an operator $\hat p$, this is an autopmorphism on the Hilbert space, i.e. $ \hat p : H \rightarrow H$, say $\hat p |\psi \rangle = |\phi \rangle$. I should think that when we want a form such that we can directly map between the elements of the Hilbert space written int the particular basis. Inserting some identities, we would want

$\int dr' \langle r|\hat p |r' \rangle \langle r'|\psi \rangle = \langle r | \phi\rangle$. Althoough this is not the same as $\hat p (r) \langle r|\psi \rangle = \langle r | \phi \rangle$, which I would think would be the analog of the abstract equality $\hat p |\psi \rangle = |\phi \rangle$, which is the one thing I am sure to be correct.

I think I am getting confused between the meaning of $r$ and $r'$, and the bra/kets $\langle r|$ etc. I think $\langle r|$ and $\langle r'|$ are effectively different elements of the basis, though I am not sure how this relates to the representation of operators.

Backrgound note: I realised that this was a lingering confusion that I should have clarified a long time ago, as it cropped up when I was attemtping a question on density matrices:

Show that the expectation value of the momentum is

$\bar{\langle p \rangle} = i \hbar \int dr \nabla_r \rho(r, r')|_{r'=r}$

EDIT: I have done a bit more investigation on pen and paper, and my current thoughts are:

- The unitarity of the operators (here Hermicity in fact) means that the automorphism induced by a particular operator (i.e. may from kets to kets) can be entirely described by the action of the operator on our chosen basis (of course, and ket can be written as a linear combination of the basis vectors, and the iperator is a linear map).

-And the object $\langle r'| \hat p | r\rangle$ as one varies $r'$, gives exactly the compenents of the ket $\hat p |r \rangle$ wrt the chosen basis. i.e the matrix elements $\langle r'| \hat p | r\rangle$ tell us how the operator transforms the kets that make up the basis. We can use this to describe how the operator transforms any ket, because we use the view that the operator .transforms the basis kets, rather than the components with respect to them.

Answer (score 3):

> The unitarity of the operators (here Hermicity in fact) means that the automorphism induced by a particular operator (i.e. may from kets to kets) can be entirely described by the action of the operator on our chosen basis.

This is a correct conclusion, but actually all you need is the linearity of the operators.

> Say $\hat p |\psi \rangle = |\phi \rangle$. [...] Inserting some identities, we would want
>   $$\int dr' \langle r|\hat p |r' \rangle \langle r'|\psi \rangle = \langle r | \phi\rangle.$$
>   Althoough this is not the same as $\hat p (r) \langle r|\psi \rangle = \langle r | \phi \rangle$, which I would think would be the analog of the abstract equality $\hat p |\psi \rangle = |\phi \rangle$, which is the one thing I am sure to be correct.

In fact, this is already exactly what you want. This might be easier to see for a finite-dimensional situation. Suppose $\hat{A} |\psi \rangle = |\phi \rangle$ and suppose we have a finite basis $|n \rangle$. Hitting both sides with $\langle m |$ and inserting an identity, we have
$$\sum_n \langle m | \hat{A} | n \rangle \langle n | \psi \rangle = \langle m | \phi \rangle$$
and upon the definitions
$$A_{mn} = \langle m | \hat{A} | n \rangle, \quad \psi_n = \langle n | \psi \rangle, \quad \phi_m = \langle m | \phi \rangle$$
we have the familiar matrix multiplication formula
$$\sum_n A_{mn} \psi_n = \phi_m.$$
One possibly confusing thing is that $|m \rangle$ and $|n \rangle$ were originally regarded as abstract vectors, but now we regard $m$ and $n$ as just indices. Indices can have any names, e.g. we could have written the formula above as
$$\sum_p A_{xp} \psi_p = \phi_x$$
without changing its meaning. However, in the bra-ket notation, the name of the vector is used to tell you what it is, in an essential way. For example, if you rename the position eigenstate $|r \rangle$ to $|p \rangle$, then everybody will get confused because there's no way to tell it apart from a momentum eigenstate.

But what if you want to talk about two different position eigenstates? Then the convention is to use $| r \rangle$ and $| r' \rangle$, or if you're using a discrete basis, then $|m \rangle$ and $|n \rangle$. That is the kind of annoying thing about Dirac notation: $|r \rangle$ and $|r' \rangle$ are usually precisely the same vector if $r = r'$, but $|r \rangle$ and $|p \rangle$ are not, even if $r = p$ in appropriate units. It's fundamentally ambiguous, but we use it anyway because it's so slick.

> And the object $\langle r'| \hat p | r\rangle$ as one varies $r'$, gives exactly the compenents of the ket $\hat p |r \rangle$ wrt the chosen basis. i.e the matrix elements $\langle r'| \hat p | r\rangle$ tell us how the operator transforms the kets that make up the basis.

Yes, that sounds correct.

Answer (score 0):

$
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle #1 \rvert}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\lvert #1 \rangle}
\newcommand{\bracket}[2]{\langle #1 \vert #2 \rangle}
$

> What does it mean to write an operator in a particular basis representation?

Consider an arbitrary operator $\hat{A}$.
Its position representation is defined by
$$ A(r,r') = \bra{r} \hat{A} \ket{r'}   \tag{1}$$
Thus the operator $\hat{A}$ is represented by a function with 2 variables (called $r$ and $r'$ here).

Now, how is $ \ket{\phi} = \hat{A} \ket{\psi}$ mapped to the position representation?
$$\begin{align}
  \phi(r) &= \bracket{r}{\phi} \\
  &= \bra{r} \hat{A} \ket{\psi} \\
  &= \bra{r} \hat{A} \left( \int dr' \ket{r'}\bra{r'} \right) \ket{\psi} \\
  &= \int dr' \bra{r} \hat{A} \ket{r'}\bracket{r'}{\psi}  \\
  &\stackrel{(1)}= \int dr' A(r,r') \psi(r')  \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

I'm not sure I got you when you write about momentum operator $\hat{p}$.
So I might miss the topic below.

Now consider the momentum operator $\hat{p}$,
or rather its 3 components $\hat{p}_x$, $\hat{p}_y$, $\hat{p}_z$.
They are just special cases of the general operator $\hat{A}$ above.
But in the position representation they have some special difficulties.
Consider the operator $\hat{p}_x$.
It has an awkward position representation (with a derivative of Dirac function)
$$ p_x(r,r') = \bra{r} \hat{p}_x \ket{r'} = i\hbar \delta'(x-x') $$

This can be seen by applying equation (2) for $\ket{\phi} = \hat{p}_x \ket{\psi}$. We get
$$
\begin{align}
  \phi(r)
  &= \int dr' p_x(r,r') \psi(r') \\
  &= i\hbar \int dr' \delta'(x-x') \psi(r') \\
  &= -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \psi(r)
\end{align}
$$
Now, this is the familiar position representation of the momentum operator,
although it doesn't look very much like equation (2) anymore.
This may also be written as
$$ \bracket{r}{\phi} = -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \bracket{r}{\psi} $$